# Create a personalized CSS class for a only one screen in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I had created a personalized CSS class. I would like to know how I can use this class only in one screen (for example sm) and not in others. I use bootstrap. My class has the property font-size 2.9vw and it is perfect to sm screens but it is so big to md or lg screens. I don't want to use media querys because it is a bootstrap task.
Can I use xs,md,lg... with my own class in bootstrap? What can I do to resolve it please?

Comment: Use media Queries

Comment: Css classes of bootstrap are just like normal classes. First give the containing div of the page a custom class say "abc" then you can use the selector ".abc .md" in your css file

Comment: So... can I use <div class = "myOwnClass .md ">? and this class only run to md screens?

Answer (score 1):

You can sync your class with bootsrap 4 grid. Use some of this with your class

```
.your-class {font-size 2.9vw}   

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    /*sm equivalent*/
    /*put your class here*/
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /*md equivalent*/
    /*put your class here*/
} 
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    /*lg equivalent*/
    /*put your class here*/
    .your-class {font-size 1.9vw}
} 
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /*xl equivalent*/
    /*put your class here*/
}
```

**UPDATED**

For Bootstrap-only-no-media solution you will have to clone your element with the same content like

```
<style>
.my-class-1 {font-size 2.9vw}
.my-class-2 {font-size 1.9vw} 
</style>
<!-- Visible only on xl -->
<div class="my-class-1 d-none d-xl-block">My text</div>
<!-- Hidden only on xl -->
<div class="my-class-2 d-xl-none">My text</div>
```

More about [bootstrap 4 display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/). But using *media* is more attractive way.

Comment: aren't there any more solution?

Comment: Updated the answer, but I suggest you to use media.